# Having trouble with reading a txt file with one line and multiple variables

Tags: java, exception, text, indexoutofboundsexception, filewriter

(Fixed) I am new to Java (Which you probably will be able to tell by the inefficiency of code) and I am having a problem reading data from a text file.

Here is an example of how I create the file and write my data to the file.

```
  final String GString = "c:/GradeCalc/java/files";
        Path Gpath = Paths.get(GString);
        if (Files.notExists( Gpath )){
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(Gpath);
            } catch (IOException e2) {

                System.out.println(e2);
            }
        }

        final String Gfile = "Grades.txt";
         Path filePath = Paths.get(GString, Gfile);
         if (Files.notExists (filePath)) {

            try {
                Files.createFile (filePath);
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                System.out.println(e1);
            }
        }

        File gradeFile = filePath.toFile();
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter (gradeFile))))
        {

            if (BQ1Num != null){
            out.print(BQ1Num + "\t" );
            }else{
                out.print("0.0"+"\t");}
            if (BQ2Num != null){
                out.print(BQ2Num + "\t" );
                }else{
                    out.print("0.0"+"\t");}
            if (BQ3Num != null){
                out.print(BQ3Num + "\t" );
                }else{
                    out.print("0.0"+"\t");}
            if (BQ4Num != null){
                out.println(BQ4Num + "\t" );
                }else{
                    out.println("0.0"+"\t");}

                out.close ();
        }
            catch (IOException a)
            {
                System.out.println (a);
                }
```

Writting the data to the file seems to work perfectly. My problem arrises when I try to read that data and set it to a variable.

Here is an example of how I attempt to read the data from said file and assign the data to variables, then use those variables.

```
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Gfile))){

                String line = in.readLine();

                while(line != null){
                String[] columns = line.split("\t");
                BQ1RetrievedNum = columns [0];
                BQ2RetrievedNum = columns [1];
                BQ3RetrievedNum = columns [2];
                BQ4RetrievedNum = columns [3];

                 line = in.readLine();
                }
                }

            catch(IOException b){

                System.out.println(b);

            }




    if (BQ1RetrievedNum != null ){
    BQ1.setText("   Quarter 1  " +BQ1RetrievedNum+ "%");
    }
    if (BQ2RetrievedNum != null){
    BQ2.setText("   Quarter 2  " +BQ2RetrievedNum+ "%");
    }
    if (BQ3RetrievedNum != null){
    BQ3.setText("   Quarter 3  " +BQ1RetrievedNum+ "%");
    }
    if (BQ4RetrievedNum != null){
    BQ4.setText("   Quarter 4  " +BQ1RetrievedNum+ "%");
    }
```

Whenever I run my program, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. 
I've been searching for hours on how to fix this exception, but with no success.

Here is what the contents of the Grades.txt look like.

43.0    0.0 0.0 0.0

Here is the code for the fileReader that I now have after some editing.

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Gfile))){

                String line = in.readLine();
                line = in.readLine();
                  String[]columns = line.split("\t");
                  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                       if(i<columns.length) {
                          switch(i) {
                             case 1:  BQ1RetrievedNum = columns[0];
                                      break;
                             case 2:  BQ2RetrievedNum = columns[1];
                                      break;
                             case 3:  BQ3RetrievedNum = columns[2];
                                    break;
                             case 4:  BQ4RetrievedNum = columns [3];
                                    break;


                       }
                  }
                }
            }


            catch(IOException b){

                System.out.println(b);

            }
```

I keep getting a  `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
 String[]columns = line.split("\t");
```

This is the code for my repaired reader.

```
 try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath, ENCODING )){
                  String line = null;
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);
                String[]columns = line.split("/");
                BQ1RetrievedNum = "";
                BQ2RetrievedNum = "";
                BQ3RetrievedNum = "";
                BQ4RetrievedNum = "";

                System.out.println(columns.length);

                for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                    if(i<columns.length) {
                       switch(i) {
                          case 0:  BQ1RetrievedNum = columns[0];
                                   break;
                          case 1:  BQ2RetrievedNum = columns[1];
                                   break;
                          case 2:  BQ3RetrievedNum = columns[2];
                                 break;
                          case 3:  BQ4RetrievedNum = columns[3];
                                 break;


                       }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("1: "+BQ1RetrievedNum);
                System.out.println("2: "+BQ2RetrievedNum);
                System.out.println("3: "+BQ3RetrievedNum);
                System.out.println("4: "+BQ4RetrievedNum);

                  }
                }



            catch(IOException b){

                System.out.println(b);

            }
```

Comment: What does `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` signify? What does `String[] columns = line.split("\t");` do?

Comment: It is pretty evident from the error that columns array does not have the elements you are expecting. Can you try printing the columns array using Arrays.toString(columns);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what is the length of the array

```
System.out.println(columns.length);
```

It may not contains expected number of values

EDIT: Following code work for me. Case values are edited.

```
String line = "43.0 0.0 0.0 0.0";
    String[]columns = line.split("\t");
    String output1 = "";
    String output2 = "";
    String output3 = "";
    String output4 = "";

    System.out.println(columns.length);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        if(i<columns.length) {
           switch(i) {
              case 0:  output1 = columns[0];
                       break;
              case 1:  output2 = columns[1];
                       break;
              case 2:  output3 = columns[2];
                     break;
              case 3:  output4 = columns[3];
                     break;
           }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("1: "+output1);
    System.out.println("2: "+output2);
    System.out.println("3: "+output3);
    System.out.println("4: "+output4);
```

[String.split("")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't throw NullPointerException

Comment: I did as you suggested and my array only has one element. I am now trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, that solved many of my proplems. Now I have some other problems to work out. The method in.readLine is reading the files contents as one of my variables, Num, not the actual line.

Comment: The `in.readLine` does not read the contents of Grade.txt as "43.0/0.0/0.0/0.0/". Everything else works perfectly. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @user2905618 have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file
And be generous to accept an answer as the answer or upvote the answers if they are help full.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thanks to you and @Maroun Maroun I figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When you [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) according to `\t`:

`String[] columns = line.split("\t");`

You don't check the *length* of the returned array. You're getting the [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in one of these lines:

```
BQ1RetrievedNum = columns [0];
BQ2RetrievedNum = columns [1];
BQ3RetrievedNum = columns [2];
BQ4RetrievedNum = columns [3];
```

Before doing that, make sure the array has 4 elements.

---

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
   if(i<columns.length) {
      switch(i) {
         case 1:  BQ1RetrievedNum = columns[0];
                  break;
         case 2:  BQ2RetrievedNum = columns[1];
                  break;
         //...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the excetion in BQ2retrievedNum = columns[2]; My array only has one element. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can have an `if` before you try to access this element.

Comment: (Correction, the exception is in BQ2retrievedNum = columns[1]) I tried to add an `if` statement, and it didn't seem to help. Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding how the code works and how to use it in my existing code. Sorry for the inconvenience.